# Is there an api to submit queueable job? [Api for System.enqueueJob]

Tags: rest-api, queueable-apex, queueable

Is there an api that allows to submit Queueable jobs? (basically which simulates System.enqueueJob)

Searched Rest Api and other apis but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't such an API. You could write your own via @RestResource, InvocableMethod, and/or webservice, or you could call Execute Anonymous (requires limited System Admin permissions). Presumably, no such API was written because you can also pass in parameters, which might mean needing to do queries, other DML, etc before actually queuing the job, so being forced to build your own API via Apex would be desirable.

Comment: We are working on external scheduler for Salesforce so we were already following approach of constructing a simple apex script and run it via executeAnonymous. While doing that, just wanted to explore and see if we missed any api. Thx for confirming that there is no such api yet.